# Is there a brain wallet feature for generating your EOS wallet private keys?

Tags: wallet, brain-wallet

How can one generate an EOS private key for cold storage using a brain wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the eosjs library to generate eos keys by providing a text string.

I have this integrated into my brain/paper wallet generator:

https://xcubicle.github.io/memorypaperwallet

Just type in a user / pass combination and it will always generate the same keys. The generation is time and memory intensive to prevent brute force guessing.